# Bind just in one way

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular6, subscribe, behaviorsubject

I have a table with users, and when click want to update. I create a service to do that.

The problem is that in the edit form when i start editing the table edits, is like a two way binding, I don't want to edit both sides. If i take out the () on [(ngModel)] when I click on edit button the editted data didn't populate.

When click on cell

```
this.dataService.setUser(row);
```

My dataService

```
public currentUser = new Subject<User>();
setUser(user) {
    this.currentUser.next(user);
}
```

My edit component

```
this.dataService.currentUser.subscribe(value => this.user = value);
```

I search everywhere and can't find an answer, maybe creating an object in the middle and then destroyed, but don't know how to do that.

Here is an image, imgur.com/a/yq3yFNC The thing is that I don't want the two way binding, because first I have to press the button bellow to validate. I just need a bind in one way. (At this moment if I edit bellow It  edit my table)

[Here is the example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions51987641angular-6-bind-jus-xcohzl).

I can't use `[value]` or `[ngModel]` because, It didn't return the value to my object user. Thats why I use `[(ngModel)]`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your "read" display and your "edit" display are bound to the same object. You still want to use two-way binding, however you want to bind them to different objects.

Instead of assigning the edit object to the same thing that the "read" display is using, instead you should copy the object's properties.

**Edit Component**

```
this.dataService.currentUser.subscribe(value => this.user = {...value});
```

Then whenever you want to save the values, you can either assign the properties back to the original object or simply replace the old object with the new one.

One way you could accomplish this is by storing a reference to the original object as well as the copied values the edit component will operate on:

```
this.dataService.currentUser.subscribe(value => {
  this.original = value;
  this.user = {...value};
});

save() {
  Object.assign(this.user, this.original)
}
```

---

Note: This is a shallow copy, meaning simple values like numbers and strings will be copied, but object references will stay the same. If you need a deep copy, you can search on SO - there are many different solutions to that problem.

---

### Old answer addressing the wrong issue

The short answer is that your edit cell doesn't know that its data has changed. Because your click was on a different component, Angular only re-checks the component that was interacted with. You need to manually tell Angular that the component has changes

**Edit Component**

```
constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

this.dataService.currentUser.subscribe(value => {
  this.user = value;
  this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
});
```

---

More detailed explanation: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: Sorry my bad english and I'm new on StackOverflow. 
Here is an image, 
https://imgur.com/a/yq3yFNC
The thing is that I don't want the two way binding, because first I have to press the button bellow to validate. I just need a bind in one way.
Thanks!

Comment: @Agustin Thanks for the clarification, you may want to add that to your question for other people to see. I've updated my answer to (hopefully) address the issue you're actually facing

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) instead of [(ngModel)]

after input `Agustin123` into *2nd edit*, you can get the output you want

[the online example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions51987641angular-6-bind-jus-corvhd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedit%2Fedit.component.html)

```
 <!-- <input [(ngModel)]="user.name"> -->

 <input [ngModel]="user.name" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" >
```

> The ngModel data property sets the element's value property and the ngModelChange event property listens for changes to the element's value.

references

- [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel)

---

**Old Answer**

you can use `complete` after `next` in your *data.service*

online example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions51987641angular-6-bind-just-in-on?file=src/app/data.service.ts

```
  setUser(user) {
    this.currentUser.next(user);
    this.currentUser.complete();
  }
```

Comment: I tried that. But still binding two way.. :(.. 
Maybe is a bug.

Comment: in my online example?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions51987641angular-6-bind-jus-bbxnlo
I edit your example, with my problem ;D

Comment: What steps should I take to figure out your problem in your [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions51987641angular-6-bind-jus-bbxnlo) ?

Comment: 1- click me
2- edit input
3- shouldn't change the name upside

Comment: you can use [value] instead of [(ngModel)]  try to use [the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions51987641angular-6-bind-jus-emakhw?file=src/app/edit/edit.component.html)

Comment: The problem is that if I use [value] the changes I do, didn't reflect on the object I have to save on database.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions51987641angular-6-bind-jus-xcohzl

Comment: OK,I modified my answer,you can check it